# Unable to find files and desktop settings after updating Kubuntu in the software center

Tags: updates, kubuntu, software-center, update-manager

I am using Kubuntu 21.04.  I just update (`not upgrade`) Kubuntu from default software-center.  After a successful update, I tried to access my local files stored in another drive (128GB), but that drive is now empty. It had around 128GB data in it. Not only this, after this update, my all data stored in `/home/abhishek/` (13GB) and `/var/www/html/`(50GB). was gone(may be deleted or something else).  My desktop settings and themes are also gone. I am using dual boot (Kubuntu + Windows 10). I restarted my PC and logged back in but unfortunately, Result is still same.

I was also working in a project, but I cannot find it now.

Is there any method to get this data back?

**EDIT 1:**
Output of `df -h`

```
abhishek@abhishek-kamal:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           779M  1.9M  777M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   57G   13G   41G  24% /
tmpfs           3.9G   43M  3.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p9   13G  470M   12G   4% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p1  256M   44M  213M  18% /boot/efi
tmpfs           779M   76K  779M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p4  128G   94M  128G   1% /media/abhishek/EXTRA SSD
```

My data gone from `/dev/nvme0n1p4`, `/dev/nvme0n1p5` and `/dev/nvme0n1p9`

#### EDIT 2:

Output of `/var/log/apt/history.log`
This output is telling what update was for -

```
Start-Date: 2021-09-30  06:56:40
Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'
Requested-By: abhishek (1000)
Upgrade: libreoffice-calc:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), udev:amd64 (247.3-3ubuntu3.4, 247.3-3ubuntu3.6), uno-libs-private:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), libreoffice-base-core:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:21.04.16, 1:21.04.17), libreoffice-core:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (93.0.4577.82-1, 94.0.4606.61-1), systemd-timesyncd:amd64 (247.3-3ubuntu3.4, 247.3-3ubuntu3.6), php8.0-soap:amd64 (8.0.10-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), libpam-systemd:amd64 (247.3-3ubuntu3.4, 247.3-3ubuntu3.6), libreoffice-common:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), ure:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), php8.0-common:amd64 (8.0.10-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.0-curl:amd64 (8.0.10-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), libreoffice-draw:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), libapache2-mod-php8.0:amd64 (8.0.10-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), libsystemd0:amd64 (247.3-3ubuntu3.4, 247.3-3ubuntu3.6), php8.0-imap:amd64 (8.0.10-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.0-intl:amd64 (8.0.10-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.0:amd64 (8.0.10-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), libnss-systemd:amd64 (247.3-3ubuntu3.4, 247.3-3ubuntu3.6), libllvm12:amd64 (1:12.0.0-3ubuntu1~21.04.1, 1:12.0.0-3ubuntu1~21.04.2), libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), libuno-cppu3:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), libreoffice-impress:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), php8.0-opcache:amd64 (8.0.10-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), fonts-opensymbol:amd64 (2:102.12+LibO7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 2:102.12+LibO7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), systemd:amd64 (247.3-3ubuntu3.4, 247.3-3ubuntu3.6), libudev1:amd64 (247.3-3ubuntu3.4, 247.3-3ubuntu3.6), php8.0-gd:amd64 (8.0.10-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), libreoffice-style-colibre:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), libreoffice-writer:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), libreoffice-plasma:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), libuno-salhelpergcc3-3:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), libreoffice-style-breeze:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), php8.0-mbstring:amd64 (8.0.10-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.0-mysql:amd64 (8.0.10-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), python3-uno:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt:amd64 (1:21.04.16, 1:21.04.17), libuno-sal3:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), php8.0-readline:amd64 (8.0.10-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.0-cli:amd64 (8.0.10-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.0-dev:amd64 (8.0.10-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), systemd-sysv:amd64 (247.3-3ubuntu3.4, 247.3-3ubuntu3.6), libreoffice-math:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:21.04.16, 1:21.04.17), shim-signed:amd64 (1.50+15.4-0ubuntu7, 1.51+15.4-0ubuntu9), php8.0-xml:amd64 (8.0.10-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.0-zip:amd64 (8.0.10-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), libreoffice-kf5:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), libreoffice-qt5:amd64 (1:7.1.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, 1:7.1.6-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-09-30  06:57:59
```

#### Edit 3:

Output of
[/var/log/syslog](https://github.com/abhishekml121/Kubuntu/blob/master/syslog)

#### Edit 4:

I had 50GB of data in `/var/www/html/` which is the location of PHP projects and 12.9GB approx data in `/home/abhishek/`. I wondered why am I not able to see my data in `/var/www/html/`, `/home/abhishek/` and ``/dev/nvme0n1p4` and why my system-settings has reseted, themes deleted, chrome sign-out. One more things when my update process was running, after 1 minute, Kubuntu hangs, So I restarted my laptop.

Eg, I was enabled `tap-to-click` with touchpad, but now tap-to-click is not working because I have to re-enable it again.

Comment: There is nothing in an update that will "reset" a computer or wipe out hundreds of gigabytes of data without your knowledge and consent. Do you see anything in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/apt/history.log` that might show what happened? Can you also [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of `df -h`? This will provide a little visibility to see whether files have been deleted or something else is blocking visibility.

Comment: @matigo updated my question, please see and help me if possible.

Comment: @Nmath I didn't plug any USB to my laptop from last 1 month. I am using `disk-uasge-analyzer` to view represntation of my data.

Comment: During my update process, My Kubuntu gave a warning for `low disk space`. Only 128MB space is remaining. After this warning I freed 1GB of data from my home folder (during update process was running).

Comment: I just woke up, restated my PC, loged-in to kubuntu, Opened chrome, Kubnutu gave a notification for the update. So I updated it and all this thing happened.

Comment: @matigo Please see my edit 2 and edit 3

Comment: Something's not adding up. How could `/home/abhishek/` contain 50GB of data if the `/home` directory is on a 13GB partition? Is there a possibility that you moved your home directory to a partition that isn't visible, such as `/dev/nvme0n1p8` (for example)? If so, we may be looking at remounting a partition to fix `/home`. As for the blank `/dev/nvme0n1p4`, there is nothing in the GitHub log nor the install history that mentions or would modify that device. Given the 94MB usage, it looks like a `mkfs` command may have been used on it to (re)create a file system 

Comment: *13GB partition? You are right. I had 50GB of data in `/var/www/html/` which is the location of `PHP projects` and 12.9GB approx data in `/home/abhishek/`. I wondered why am I not able to see my data in `/var/www/html/`, `/home/abhishek/` and `/dev/nvme0n1p4` and why my system-settings has reseted, themes deleted, chrome sign-out. One more things when my update process was running, after 1 minute, Kubuntu hangs, So I restarted my laptop.

Comment: it looks like a `mkfs`*, I didn't do any thing. I was opened only chrome, file-browser and software-updater during updation.

Comment: No I didn't use `mkfs`. (I was answring the question of @matigo in my above comment). Actually I brought a new laptop, So I moved important data from my old laptop to this new one. A new update came from Kubuntu, I did update and this worst thing happened.

Comment: Your syslog shows that `fsck` was run on `/dev/nvme0n1p9` and that a lot of orphaned inodes were found and repaired/removed.  This is a common symptom of hard drive failure.  Perhaps the hard drive is on it's way out?

Comment: I still didn't get my wiped data. I can use all partition as before. So no hard-drive failture. As I already told that I haven't done any terminal task or root level task. I was opened chrome, file-browser and software-updater during updation. I am also wondering how this happened.